# Webbrowser control not loading browser addons (browser extension)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have installed one addons for IE browser. Which gives result on google search and display it on top of the google search result.

However, this addons work on browser window but when I load browser in WPF with webbrowser control then this addons is not getting display.

Please help !!!!

Comment: What is the version of IE browser you are using??

Comment: WebBrowser control uses IE by default. If you want to use IE 11 in your browser control then you need to specify it in your html. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting your webBrowser to use IE11 then include the following meta tag in the html file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

IE addon/pluggins should automatically load when using webbrowser control unless there are security issues to prevent it.  Check your system DEP (Data Execution Prevention) settings if is not set to `AlwaysOn`. Also make your application target X86 platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!!! I am opening google page directly. How can I disable security permission for Addons

Comment: you mean ActiveX security permissions??

Comment: try this <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet --> add this tag just below <!Doctype html> and above <html> tag

Comment: I am opening http://www.google.com/#q=searchtext this URL from web browser control. and I want to load addons.